# Centre blenders origin when scaling

Tags: modeling

Hi I've done something and when I scale my object the origin of the blender axis goes off to the side I want to keep it central.[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please show more pictures and explain more in detail? Scaling should not change the origin...

Answer (score 0):

Scaling should not change the objects origin.
If what you mean is that you would like to scale around the origin, hit object -> reset origin -> Then hit the button on the right of the blue oval and select object boundaries rather than individual origins
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I selected the object, then put the coordinates 0, 0, 0 to recenter the object.